# Maven tomcat:run issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I tried running the [Spring PetClinic](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic) project from eclipse (with m2e plugin installed).

My pom.xml config,

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
    <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
    <port>9966</port>
    <path>/petclinic</path>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I do tomcat:run from eclipse I get this log,

```
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) < compile @ spring-petclinic <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ spring-petclinic ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/spring-petclinic
```

But when I check if the app is up nothing comes up. 
I tried both -

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-petclinic/
http://localhost:9966/petclinic/
```

Please advice.

Comment: What does "nothing comes up" exactly mean? Do you get a 404 error in your browser? Do you get an empty page? ...

Comment: I get a 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <path>/</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Use command:

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

If still error, check what are under the hood by command:

```
mvn -X tomcat7:run
```

**Reference:** http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Answer (score 0):

The goal you should use is:

```
tomcat7:run
```

Instead:

```
tomcat:run
```

That's why in your log appears:

```
tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1 and port 8080
```

Instead:

```
tomcat-maven-plugin:2.2 and port 9966
```